# Create vb class and call it in form_load

Tags: vb.net

I am a new in vb.net world.
Now, I am trying to create vb class in my program and I copy the following code from form1_load.
It was running well when I put it in the form_load.
But now, I want to set this following code in my vb class and call the created vb class in my form_load.
But I get an error info in my vb class, it says;

> 'txtId' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
> level.
>
> 'txtUsername' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.
>
> 'txtPassword' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.
>
> 'txtDept' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.

I don't know how to do that.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient    
Namespace Common
    Public Class DataAccess
        Private Function GetData(ByVal ID As String) As String
            Dim constr As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-M176S3L\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True"
            Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from [TEST].dbo.login where Id = 1")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        sdr.Read()
                        txtId.Text = sdr("Id").ToString()
                        txtUsername.Text = sdr("Username").ToString()
                        txtPassword.Text = sdr("Password").ToString()
                        txtDept.Text = sdr("Dept").ToString()
                    End Using
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Remove all the Controls' references from that class. Make it return a class object (or a collection of objects, or a DataTable) that contains the values read from the database and assign the values to the Controls using what `GetData()` returns. -- You `GetData()` is a method that should return a string, but it doesn't return anything (I don't know why you set that Type as the returned value). As mentioned, don't add references (the Controls) to class that is meant to query a database, hence it has nothing to do with the UI. Let the UI handlers manage the data you get from the db.

Comment: I am really sorry, I did not understand. I am very new in vb world.

Comment: Start by removing any Control reference from the `GetData()` method (which BTW, accepts and `ID` argument, but you never us it and hard-code an ID in the query instead) -- You can make the `GetData()` method `Shared` -- Now, you have to return the values you have read from the db to the caller. How do you return all those values? You could build a class object that stores the data. Which is quite specific to the query you're running. So you could also change the Method name in, e.g., `GetTestDataByID()`, which returns a specialized object that contains the data.

Comment: BTW, avoid `SELECT *`, specify the Columns you're retrieving explicitly.

Comment: BTW2, the method accepts a string argument for the ID, but it appears the ID is actually an integer (as it is supposed to be), so also change the Type of that parameter, to avoid *confusion*.

Comment: finally I did it, thank you so much for your explanation :)